# what is best used to optimize sfml project?

Tags: c++, 2d, shader, sfml

do 2d project simulator life. When there are many organisms, the project begins to hang, resulting in a marked decrease in the speed of organisms. What can you recommend? Perhaps the use of shaders to draw or there is something really useful?

Comment: Use a profiler first, otherwise you're going to end up solving problems you don't have  and ignoring the ones you do.

Comment: thanks, 
problems remain with one window.draw, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It's gonna be difficult to help you without your code but I can still give you a few advices based on my own experience.
Since you're working with many "entities", there is probably some kind of interaction between these entities. If that is the case, a  [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) (or a simple grid) could help lower the complexity of your algorithm.
But most of the time, SFML applications are slow due to inefficient rendering. There are a few ways to decrease rendering time :

- Drawing everything at once (putting all your vertices in one array and draw that once instead  of drawing a thousand rectangles one by one)
- Drawing simpler objects (ex.: points instead of rectangles)
- Drawing less often; You don't have to draw every time you update. Have a clock measuring the time since the last update and draw when the time (1/60th of a second for 60 FPS) is exceeded.

I don't know much about shaders but they seem a bit overkill for the job you wanna do.